# das Experiment + Präposition

Tags: preposition

What is the correct preposition construct for the expression?

> the experiment **on** the whole population

Comment: What do you think might be the correct preposition? Your question does not show any research effort in trying to find the right answer before asking us. This site is not a translation service. And you did not provide us with enough context to be able to answer the question correctly without making any assumptions. As a minimum context at least a whole sentence would be needed. Phrases without context can be interpreted in many different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me extend the phrase a bit:

> to conduct the experiment ***on*** the *whole population*

In order to translate it correctly, we must first figure out what the term *whole population* refers to:

1. in terms of statistics to all individuals of the basic population under consideration

    → *gesamte Population* or *Grundgesamtheit*
2. generally to all inhabitants of a geographic or political area

    → *gesamte Bevölkerung* or *Gesamtbevölkerung*

If the statistical term is intended, then the preposition ***mit*** is typically used:

> 1. das Experiment ***mit*** der Grundgesamtheit durchführen

If the general term is intended, then (at least) the two prepositions ***mit*** and ***an*** are possible:

> 2. a) das Experiment ***mit*** der gesamten Bevölkerung durchführen
>
>     b) das Experiment ***an*** der gesamten Bevölkerung durchführen

While a) is quite neutral, b) has the slightly negative connotation that humans serve as guinea pigs. This may be so because ***an*** is more often used in connection with objects. It, therefore, objectifies the humans who take part in an experiment. An experimenter myself, I always reply, when asked, that I do psychophysical experiments ***mit** Menschen*, not ***an** Menschen*.

Answer (score 1):

Without any context, I'd say "das Experiment an der ganzen Bevölkerung", but this sounds somewhat negative, which might not be intended.